# Select records even if doesn't exists

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have database with 4 tables:

1. First table represents rooms and has single column called "RoomNumber".
2. Second table is Hours and has single column "HourNumber".
3. Third table is Days and has two columns "DayNumber" and "DayName".
4. Last table is TimeTables of rooms and it's a relation table between the three other tables.

The last table has the following columns:

- RoomNumber
- DayNumber
- HourNumber
- Subject (what's happening at the specific hour and day)

but this table stores only records with rooms that has Subject (it keep only busy hours of rooms), it doesn't presents records with empty subjects so it can't show me when a chosen room is available (no subject means the room is clear).

I want to somehow write a query that will give me the status of all the rooms in a specific day and hour.

For example this query returns all the busy rooms at day 1, hour 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM TimeTables
WHERE HourNumber = 1 AND DayNumber = 1
```

But I want to get the status of all the rooms at the specific time, I know the rest of the records doesn't exists.

Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: use an outer join

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please share sample data, and the expected result. Depending on what you want exactly, you might need to do an outer join with a dummy table, which requires some trickery in Access.

Comment: it's difficult for me to explain it but for example the table:
<code>
RoomNumber DayNumber HourNumber Subject
23  1  1  discussionA
24  1  2  discussionB
25  1  1  discussionC
26  2  3  discussionD
27  3  1  discussionE
</code>
The aforementioned query will return this:
<code>
RoomNumber DayNumber HourNumber Subject
23  1  1  discussionA
25  1  1  discussionC
</code>
but I want somthing like this:
<code>
RoomNumber DayNumber HourNumber Subject
23  1  1  discussionA
24  1  1  null
25  1  1  discussionC
26  1  1  null
27  1  1  null
</code>

Comment: sorry but I'm not sure how to edit it in a readable table :(

Comment: Format the table text as CODE or BLOCKQUOTE.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the status of the rooms in MS Access, I think a correlated subquery is the simplest method:

```
select r.*,
       (select tt.subject
        from TimeTables as tt
        where tt.RoomNumber = r.RoomNumber and tt.HourNumber = 1 and tt.DayNumber = 1
       ) as subject_1_1
from rooms as r;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this query doesn't work, it gives me an error of memo fields

Comment: @Black-Wolf . . . There is no mention of "memo" fields anywhere in the question.  Your comment doesn't make sense.